# More Truth Value is Ambiguous

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, conditional-statements

I've been through lots of questions in stack overflow but still can't figure this out. I understand it's returning a Bool etc but basically I want to apply multiple conditionals to a DataFrame (If And Else, Else if...) But continue to get Ambiguous Error asking to you use any(), all()

Here is the code:

```
if (stratData['Ratio'].shift(1) < 1) & (stratData['60'].shift(1) < stratData['Ratio'].shift(1)):
    stratData['pos'] = -1
else:
    stratData['pos'] = 1
```

I'd like this to work AND also add further conditions to the stratData['pos'] column. I've tried creating a myfunc = lambda... and I've also tried np.where. Appreciate any help!

EDIT: I should have posted earlier but I would like to do multiple conditions so beyond just TRUE FALSE using [idx]

```
if (stratData['Ratio'].shift(1) < 1) & (stratData['60'].shift(1) < stratData['Ratio'].shift(1)):
    stratData['pos'] = -1
elif (stratData['Ratio'].shift(1) > 1) & (stratData['60'].shift(1) > stratData['Ratio'].shift(1)):
    stratData['pos'] = 1
else:
    stratData['pos'] = 0
```

Comment: Please put the exact wording of your error message in your question.

Comment: Btw, doesn't [tag:ambiguous] look ambiguous and redundant?

Comment: Is `stratData['pos']` a scalar (1 value) or many?

Comment: stratData['pos'] is a NEW series (or column) in existing DataFrame stratData

Answer (score 0):

Each column of your `DataFrame` is a `Series` of values, not a scalar, so your logical expression:

```
((stratData['Ratio'].shift(1) < 1) &
 (stratData['60'].shift(1) < stratData['Ratio'].shift(1)))
```

will evaluate to a `Series` of type `bool`, not a scalar. Suppose that some of the elements are `True` and some are `False` - should the next line under your `if` statement be executed or not? It's ambiguous. For that reason, an `if` statement must always be followed by an expression that can be safely cast to a *scalar* boolean value.

Looking at your code, you might be trying to do one of two quite different things:

1. "If *all* of the elements in the series are `True` then set *all* of the values in the `'pos'` column to `-1`". In this case, you could do:

   ```
   if np.all((stratData['Ratio'].shift(1) < 1) &
             (stratData['60'].shift(1) < stratData['Ratio'].shift(1))):
       stratData['pos'] = -1
   ```
2. "For *each* element in the series that is `True`, set the *corresponding* element in the `'pos'` column to `-1`". In this case you could use the series as a boolean index into `stratData['pos']`:

   ```
   idx = ((stratData['Ratio'].shift(1) < 1) &
          (stratData['60'].shift(1) < stratData['Ratio'].shift(1)))
   stratData[idx]['pos'] = -1
   ```

My guess is that you probably want option #2.

---

I see that you've edited your question. Since you say *"using [idx]"* I assume  that option 2 was what you wanted. If you want to test multiple conditions then you can simply generate multiple sets of boolean indices, e.g.:

```
idx1 = ((stratData['Ratio'].shift(1) < 1) &
        (stratData['60'].shift(1) < stratData['Ratio'].shift(1)))
stratData[idx1]['pos'] = -1

idx2 = ((stratData['Ratio'].shift(1) > 1) &
        (stratData['60'].shift(1) > stratData['Ratio'].shift(1)))
stratData[idx2]['pos'] = 1

# NB: "~" means "bitwise not" and "|" means "bitwise or"
idx3 = ~(idx1 | idx2)
stratData[idx3]['pos'] = 0
```

Comment: TYVM, works exactly right! Curious, is there a 'cleaner' version of your above code that doesn't require multiple idx for each condition?

Comment: @user2977664 Well you could always loop over each row of your `DataFrame` and use `if ... else` statements to do the conditional assignment for a single element at a time, but this will almost certainly be slower than doing vectorized assignments using index arrays. There is also the [`.where()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#the-where-method-and-masking) method, but this does essentially the same thing as creating a boolean index array.